# Monitor several GCP projects using Elastic stack

Tags: elasticsearch, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, monitoring, elastic-stack

I have several GCP projects, belonging to different people. I have all accesses on them. None of them have an Organization set.
I would like to monitor those projects (metrics from VM, logs etc) and display a centralized dashboard with relevant information and filters.

What I have currently is a GCP project with an Elastic stack installed and running (using [this repo](https://github.com/sherifabdlnaby/elastdocker)).
My idea would be that all the projects send metrics continuously to the Elastic URL of my project and using Kibana I can display a health status and metrics of all the projects on a dashboard.

I found [this tutorial](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/observability/current/gcp-dataflow.html) using data-flows but I have trouble making it works. Here is what I did:

- Create a Pub/Sub topic, a sink and subscription on the project I want to monitor
- Create a VPC and a NAT in the project because I need to know what address to allow on my Elastic server.
- Create a firewall rule on my Elastic server to allow the NAT to access port 9200 and contact Elastic
- Create a data-flow on the project to monitor.

But when I launch the data-flow job, I get this error:
`Error message from worker: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot get Elasticsearch version`
[Data-flow failing job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oy8JV.png)

Is my idea correct ? If so Am I doing it the right way and why is it not working ? If not what would you suggest ?

Thank you !